# How to apply CSS changes dynamically before pages load

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I load external css from external javascript dynamically from another source to my website, which updates my webpage to the new css design.

`var link = document.createElement( "script" );
link.src = "http://externalsourcee.com/page/js/generate?token=I-css76theme";
document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( link );`

The problem: My webpage where the css is updated display first then changes the design, so the user will see the lag.

My Question: How can I ensure that the user does not see any changes taking place, the user will only see the  design once the page loads or if lag must exist then we can insert loading screen so that visitor will see progress, while the css is updated.

Caveat: I can't edit the html file, I can only make changes to it by loading javascript externally.

Comment: Normally you'd make all the content `visibility: hidden;` with a CSS rule, but if you cannot change the source you're out of luck.

Comment: Might it be an option to put a `div` in front of your entire page with a color or text? You `.show()` it at start. And you `.hide()` it when done.

Comment: @Sparky, would that work dynamically?, remember I can only edit the page by inserting divs, other html elements and script using javascript only.
Will inserting div dynamically not show lag?

Comment: You got an interesting question here. I'll follow the answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function to load another css.

you can also put please wait using javascript and css for user so they can wait util design updates.

i hope it will help you.